# Why do I get invalid JSON payload when calling google cloud vision API from appcelerator?

Tags: google-api, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, google-vision

I was trying to use Google vision API v1 by Alloy Appcelerator

I create a request HTTPClient and call API https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=MY_APP_KEY

But i have get response text from google :

```
  {
 error = {
     code = 400;
     details = (
                  {
                     "@type" = "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest";
                      fieldViolations = ({
                                        description = "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"request\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'request' could not be found in request message.";
                                        });
                  }
                );
     message = "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"request\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'request' could not be found in request message.";
     status = "INVALID_ARGUMENT";
  };
```

}

And there is my code use HTTP request by Alloy

```
var requests =  
{
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
        "content": "image_have_encodebase64",
      },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"TEXT_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.open("POST", 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=MY_APP_KEY');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(requests));
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Having a look at the API, I've noticed that the array name should be requests (plural) not request. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it get same error if i change request to requests

Comment: Did you try to JSON.stringify() it? Like:  ```xhr.send(JSON.stringify(requests));```

Comment: Hi Carlos Henrique Lustosa, i try this way but do not success

Comment: I've fixed the code in your question to use requests as the [API wants](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#body.request_body) and use stringify since for POST requests Titanium will otherwise turn the object into form-encoded POST data [as documented](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-method-send). With both of these changes you are still sure it doesn't work? Could you replace the Google API URL with a [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) URL to see what the exact request is?

Comment: Dear all, i have fixed it. Because length of string i encode64 so long, so can not send it. i have to set Content-length for header. Thank  @Fokke-Appcelerator - Appcelerator , Carlos Henrique Lustosa for your support

Answer (score 7):

By setting the `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headers it should work:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", size);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Also it should be noted that Google recommends resizing your image to 1024 x 768 -- you can resize your image with:

```
img = img.imageAsResized(1024,768);
```

After making these changes to my code I had everything working.